# Unity: How to sync RenderTextures so that they all render once per frame

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, textures, render, frame

I have a Unity project which uses many cameras outputting to render textures, and then these render textures are all rendered to planes in the scene.

It is fairly obvious that on some frames, not all render textures are capturing a frame where others are. This gives a look of stuttering between frames.

Please see the below GIF which is a recording of the stuttering effect, played by frame by frame. You will so that on some frames, only sections of the image are updated and then the rest of the image 'catches up' after.

[GIF Example of Frame Stuttering](https://gfycat.com/UnfoldedIcyGossamerwingedbutterfly)

This occurs when Vsync is turned on or off.